# Parsing templates with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have this template file:

```
<!-- BEGIN TEST -->
<!-- BEGIN TEST2 -->
<!-- BEGIN TEST3 -->

<!-- END TEST3 -->
<!-- END TEST2 -->
<!-- END TEST -->
```

And this regexp to parse it:

```
 preg_match("@<!-- BEGIN (.*?) -->(.*?)<!-- END (.*?) -->@siu", $this->code, $matches);
```

**This returns (var_dump):**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(85) "<!-- BEGIN TEST -->
<!-- BEGIN TEST2 -->
<!-- BEGIN TEST3 -->

<!-- END TEST3 -->"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "TEST"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "TEST3"
}
```

How to make it work like this: `@<!-- BEGIN (.*?) -->(.*?)<!-- END %1 -->@siu` (of course this doesn't work; it's just my example to show the problem)

Comment: You'll have to explain what it is you're hoping to get instead.

Comment: Look at answer by Piotr Olaszewski.

Comment: Piotr also mentioned that he didn't know exactly what it is you were after. When asking for help, it doesn't hurt to be clear about that, don't you agree?

Comment: `@<!-- BEGIN (.*?) -->(.*?)<!-- END %1 -->@siu` - it explained it... Use first (.*?) in the place of %1.

Comment: Look, I just think you weren't clear in your original question, and so did Piotr, otherwise he wouldn't have said *"I don't know what you exacly want recive"*. You found your answer however, so let's be done with it, shall we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you exacly want recive, maybe something like this:

```
$s = '<!-- BEGIN TEST --><!-- BEGIN TEST2 --><!-- BEGIN TEST3 --><!-- END TEST3 --><!-- END TEST2 --><!-- END TEST -->';

preg_match("@<!-- BEGIN (.*?) -->(.*?)<!-- END \\1 -->@siu", $s, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```